# Accessing the date on which a contact is added to iPhone's Address Book using AddressBookUI

Tags: iphone, ios, date, addressbook, abaddressbook

Using AddressBookUI for iOS, how can I access the date a contact is added to iPhone's address book? I have downloaded an app on iPhone that shows the date contacts are added so I know for sure those info is somewhere. But I could not find out how to access those information in Address Book Programming Guide for iOS. How about the location info when the contact was added, is that also saved somewhere and I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `kABPersonCreationDateProperty`. It is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210).